# .NET Core Socket.BeginAccept missing

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core

I'm trying to do an asynchronous server using .NET Core and I'm following this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

But the problem is that Visual Studio InteliSence doesn't find the `BeginAccept` method... I checked the corefx sources on github and the `BeginAccept` method exists.

Maybe the guide for .NET Framework is not valid for the .NET Core ...

Do you have any ideas for how I can build an asynchronous server using the `Socket` class ? Thanks

EDIT:

There is my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This API is not available on .NET Core. You need to use [`AcceptAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.acceptasync(v=vs.110).aspx) instead which works in .NET Core and .NET Framework. In general, the XyzBegin and XyzEnd style async methods are not available in .NET Core.

This function is a bit different from other *Async APIs in that it does not return a Task. Instead, you pass in a `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. One of the members of this is `Completed` which is an event that is raised when the Socket completes a connection.

Full documentation and examples on usage are in the linked documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have a question, I saw in the documentation that there is a maximum number of connection represented by the `m_numConnections` field. Is a way to handle multiple clients without using a maximum number of connection? Is this sample good to handle a huge amount of clients?